# How to make a child div to grow to full screen using CSS?

Tags: css, html, greasemonkey, fullscreen

I have a child DIV under several other DIV containers. I am trying to add a button to make it to full screen using Greasemonkey script. I tried using below CSS but it isn't successful. It is just filling up to the parent container.

```
body.richText{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Is there a guaranteed way to make any selected DIV to fill the screen, irrespective of it's parent's CSS properties?

Comment: I did a quick fiddle and it works just fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/HbXFU/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolute positioning will only respect it's elder elements if it's parent or grandparent has position relative.

If you did something like:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body * {
    position:static !important;
}
```

It should guarantee that the selection fills up all of the available space. 'body *' can be substituted for whatever elder selectors are needed for the specific application to override the 'position:relative;' styles.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't confirm whether it works because my DIV is buried under a bunch of other div's and I haven't had the time to identify all of the parent DIV's. Does the property "Position: static" affect existing layout also? I would like to switch to full screen without disturbing rest of the layout, like a floating full screen window.

Comment: It will disturb the layout, yes. Ideally, you would move this DIV to a direct child of the `<body>` tag so that you didn't have to interfere with the rest of the page.